# TomEE encountering "a non-application exception", but only on windows, not on mac

Tags: java, postgresql, tomcat, servlets, javabeans

We have a database that, among other entries, contain a "Lecturer" entry. We are trying to query this, but for some reason it only works on macs. Any windows PC we try it on instead returns the error log pasted below.
Our server is a TomEE (Apache Tomcat 7.0) server using postgreSQL JDBC 1212 and it's a dynamic web project using javabeans.

This is for a school project, and none of us have any experience with these kinds of projects, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Complete errorlogs:

```
type Exception report

message The bean encountered a non-application exception; nested exception is: 

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception 
javax.ejb.EJBException: The bean encountered a non-application exception; nested exception is: 
    <openjpa-2.4.0-r422266:1674604 nonfatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: null
FailedObject: test [org.apache.openjpa.util.StringId] [java.lang.String]
    org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.convertException(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:427)
    org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.invoke(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:329)
    EAO.EAO$$LocalBeanProxy.findLecturer(EAO/EAO.java)
    controller.test.doGet(test.java:40)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)



root cause 
<openjpa-2.4.0-r422266:1674604 nonfatal general error> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException: null
FailedObject: test [org.apache.openjpa.util.StringId] [java.lang.String]
    org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.find(BrokerImpl.java:1029)
    org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.find(BrokerImpl.java:923)
    org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBroker.find(DelegatingBroker.java:230)
    org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.find(EntityManagerImpl.java:486)
    org.apache.openejb.persistence.JtaEntityManager.find(JtaEntityManager.java:180)
    EAO.EAO.findLecturer(EAO.java:93)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:192)
    org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:173)
    org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.record(StatsInterceptor.java:181)
    org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.invoke(StatsInterceptor.java:100)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:192)
    org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:173)
    org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.InterceptorStack.invoke(InterceptorStack.java:85)
    org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer._invoke(StatelessContainer.java:227)
    org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer.invoke(StatelessContainer.java:194)
    org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.synchronizedBusinessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:317)
    org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.businessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:312)
    org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler._invoke(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:92)
    org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.invoke(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:325)
    EAO.EAO$$LocalBeanProxy.findLecturer(EAO/EAO.java)
    controller.test.doGet(test.java:40)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)



root cause 
java.lang.NullPointerException
    org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.setInverseRelation(JDBCStoreManager.java:452)
    org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.initializeState(JDBCStoreManager.java:412)
    org.apache.openjpa.jdbc.kernel.JDBCStoreManager.initialize(JDBCStoreManager.java:305)
    org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingStoreManager.initialize(DelegatingStoreManager.java:112)
    org.apache.openjpa.kernel.ROPStoreManager.initialize(ROPStoreManager.java:57)
    org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.initialize(BrokerImpl.java:1048)
    org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.find(BrokerImpl.java:1006)
    org.apache.openjpa.kernel.BrokerImpl.find(BrokerImpl.java:923)
    org.apache.openjpa.kernel.DelegatingBroker.find(DelegatingBroker.java:230)
    org.apache.openjpa.persistence.EntityManagerImpl.find(EntityManagerImpl.java:486)
    org.apache.openejb.persistence.JtaEntityManager.find(JtaEntityManager.java:180)
    EAO.EAO.findLecturer(EAO.java:93)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:192)
    org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:173)
    org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.record(StatsInterceptor.java:181)
    org.apache.openejb.monitoring.StatsInterceptor.invoke(StatsInterceptor.java:100)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext$Invocation.invoke(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:192)
    org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.ReflectionInvocationContext.proceed(ReflectionInvocationContext.java:173)
    org.apache.openejb.core.interceptor.InterceptorStack.invoke(InterceptorStack.java:85)
    org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer._invoke(StatelessContainer.java:227)
    org.apache.openejb.core.stateless.StatelessContainer.invoke(StatelessContainer.java:194)
    org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.synchronizedBusinessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:317)
    org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler.businessMethod(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:312)
    org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.EjbObjectProxyHandler._invoke(EjbObjectProxyHandler.java:92)
    org.apache.openejb.core.ivm.BaseEjbProxyHandler.invoke(BaseEjbProxyHandler.java:325)
    EAO.EAO$$LocalBeanProxy.findLecturer(EAO/EAO.java)
    controller.test.doGet(test.java:40)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Answer (score 0):

We found an answer!

Turns out, we lacked the statement

```
<provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
```

in our XML document (right underneath the "persistence-unit" section).

In addition, we needed to get an eclipselink.jar file and put it in the lib folder in our TomEE install directory. This solved it!

Comment: Take care doing that you switch of JPA provider - TomEE uses by default OpenJPA as you can see in the stack. It looks like you can either miss the entities enhancing (at build time for instance) or your mapping is not valid (eclipselink can tolerate a not portable relationship mapping). Maybe double check before using that workaround.